# Including external PHP into WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, external

I am working on a Wordpress site that will become the model for several sites with the same content. The only change will be in the Blogname which we want to pull into the text with

```
 <?php bloginfo('name'); ?>
```

So the goal is to have a directory of common content on an external server that gets pulled into the each WordPress site and the appropriate styling applied. I am not a programmer but I have tried several ideas such as have a different page template for each element. Problem with that is, the code I am using:

```
    <? $a = file_get_contents("http://ew2w.com/commonPages/about.html");
echo ($a);
?>
```

only works with HTML files not php and the bloginfo command does not work. I tried adding this function:

```
 // Load Content Limit
function show_file_func( $atts ) {
  extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'file' => ''
  ), $atts ) );
  if ($file!='')
    return @file_get_contents($file);
}
add_shortcode( 'show_file', 'show_file_func' );
```

and including in the file with a shortcode. I like this idea because it allows me to have a different image above the text but it also doesn't work with PHP, the bloginfo command or pull the styling.

can anyone help> it seems like it should be that hard

Comment: This will work fine if the contents of the file are generated in php. Or you could use `cURL` to get the data. You could also create a REST endpoint and return JSON at which you parse and extrapolate data as needed.

Comment: unfortunately it only works with HTML files not PHP. I don't really understand how to write PHP so without an example code I'm not sure what to do. Ideally I want to be able to pull in text with the BlogInfo function and have it know what the blog settings is.